# Does Rust have a way to convert several bytes to a number?

Tags: numbers, type-conversion, rust

And convert a number to a byte array?

I'd like to avoid using `transmute`, but it's most important to reach maximum performance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is [`T::from_str_radix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.from_str_radix) to convert from a string (you can choose the base and `T` can be any integer type).

To convert an integer to a `String` you can use [`format!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#formatting-traits):

```
format!("{:x}", 42) == "2a"
format!("{:X}", 42) == "2A"
```

To reinterpret an integer as bytes, just use the `byte_order` crate.

---

Old answer, I don't advise this any more:

If you want to convert between `u32` and `[u8; 4]` (for example) you can use `transmute`, it’s what it is for.

Note also that Rust has [`to_be`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.to_be) and [`to_le`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.to_le) functions to deal with endianess:

```
unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<u32, [u8; 4]>(42u32.to_le()) } == [42, 0, 0, 0]
unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<u32, [u8; 4]>(42u32.to_be()) } == [0, 0, 0, 42]
unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<[u8; 4], u32>([0, 0, 0, 42]) }.to_le() == 0x2a000000
unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<[u8; 4], u32>([0, 0, 0, 42]) }.to_be() == 0x0000002a
```

Comment: As I understand T::from_str_radix convert from string, not from hex. And "format!" seems to be slowpoke, however I do really need performance.

Comment: What do you call hex then? The base only matters when the number is represented as a string. Otherwise `42` and `0x2a` are the same integer.

Comment: For example I have several bytes (bytes: &[u8; 4]) and need to get int (u32) from it.

Comment: In that case the base does not matter at all, it’s just bytes.

Comment: Yes I mean exactly it. Base doesn't matter. But how to get value of this 4 bytes into u32 variable?

Comment: I’ve added an example with transmute taking care of endianess issues.

Comment: I would recommend the byte order crate over raw transmutes; it is a safe interface, and makes sure you're considering endianness.

Comment: Looks even better, I did not know it

Comment: Don't use transmute, it is dangerous and will cause portability headaches when endianness changes. If you don't want to use the byte_order crate use bit operations (shift by multiples of 8 bits  and or), the compiler will compile it into efficient code.

Comment: std::mem::transmute from slice to integer is immediate undefined behaviour, as the slice is not aligned.

Answer (score 27):

A `u32` being 4 bytes, you **may** be able to use `std::mem::transmute` to interpret a `[u8; 4]` as a `u32` however:

- beware of **alignment**
- beware of **endianness**

A no-dependency solution is simply to perform the maths, following in [Rob Pike's steps](http://commandcenter.blogspot.fr/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html):

```
fn as_u32_be(array: &[u8; 4]) -> u32 {
    ((array[0] as u32) << 24) +
    ((array[1] as u32) << 16) +
    ((array[2] as u32) <<  8) +
    ((array[3] as u32) <<  0)
}

fn as_u32_le(array: &[u8; 4]) -> u32 {
    ((array[0] as u32) <<  0) +
    ((array[1] as u32) <<  8) +
    ((array[2] as u32) << 16) +
    ((array[3] as u32) << 24)
}
```

It compiles down to reasonably efficient code.

If dependencies are an option though, using the [byteorder](https://crates.io/crates/byteorder) crate is just simpler.

Comment: As a matter of style I would use `|` instead of `+` (and Rob Pike seems to agree).